# Python: thread not working

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with a python program that would allow users to download web images through the parallel process. Below is the code:

```
from threading import Thread
from uuid import uuid4
import urllib
import re

def concurrent_run(fun, j):
   for i in j:
       Thread(target=fn, args=(i)).start()

def find_image(i):
   newpath = '/Users/*******/Desktop'+str(uuid4())+".jpg" 
   if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
   f=open(newpath,'wb')
   f.write(from_page(i))
   f.close()

def all_images(i):
   images = re.findall('img=',i)
   return [images[i] for i in xrange(0,len(images))]

def read_page(u):
   return urllib.urlopen(u).read()

concurrent_run(find_image, all_images(read_page('http://www.google.com')))
```

...and nothing seems to happen?  can somebody please point out where I had gone wrong?

thank you

Comment: Can you bullet list the algo you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `fn` does not match with the parameter name `fun`

  ```
  def concurrent_run(fun, j):
     #               ^^^
     for i in j:
         Thread(target=fn, args=(i)).start()
         #             ^^       ^^^
  ```
- args should be an tuple: `args=(i,)`

Comment: Another minor issue to list: I think he is missing a "/" building the string for newpath in the find_image function; then why os.makedirs on it? ...